# Как call использует стек?

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, x86-64

Пытаюсь вызвать crt-шный exp. Если перейти по метке func через jmp, для вызова exp нужно отнять из rsp 32 байта (первый вариант кода). А если через call (второй вариант), то 40 байт, иначе windows выдает ошибку. Почему так происходит?

```
format PE64 console
include 'E:\Fresh\include\win64a.inc'
entry main1

section '.data' data readable writeable

        msg db '%lf',10,0

section '.text' code readable executable
main1:
        and rsp,-16
        sub rsp,32

        mov rax,1.0
        movq xmm7,rax
        jmp func
        label1:

        mov rcx,msg
        movq rdx,xmm7
        call [printf]
        mov rcx,0
        call [ExitProcess]

func:
        movsd xmm0,xmm7
        sub rsp,32
        call [exp_0]
        add rsp,32
        movsd xmm7,xmm0
        jmp label1

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

        library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL', msvcrt,'MSVCRT.DLL'
        import msvcrt, printf,'printf',exp_0,'exp'
        import kernel32, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
```

```
format PE64 console
include 'E:\Fresh\include\win64a.inc'
entry main1

section '.data' data readable writeable

        msg db '%lf',10,0

section '.text' code readable executable
main1:
        and rsp,-16
        sub rsp,32

        mov rax,1.0
        movq xmm7,rax
        call func

        mov rcx,msg
        movq rdx,xmm7
        call [printf]
        mov rcx,0
        call [ExitProcess]

func:
        movsd xmm0,xmm7
        sub rsp,40
        call [exp_0]
        add rsp,40
        movsd xmm7,xmm0
        ret

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

        library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL', msvcrt,'MSVCRT.DLL'
        import msvcrt, printf,'printf',exp_0,'exp'
        import kernel32, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница между `jmp` и `call` в том, что `call` записывает на стек адрес следующей инструкции, а затем переходит на указанный адрес. То есть, разница 8 байт. В соответствии с `VC++ calling convention`, стек должен быть выровнен по 16 байтам (stack alignment). Любая функция вызывается с с невыровненным стеком, результат `call`, и первое, что она должна сделать, это выровнять стек. Обычно это `push rbp`, а вашей программе `and rsp,-16`.

Вариант 1:

```
    jmp func

func:
   ; stack alignment 16 bytes
```

Вариант 2:

```
    call func      ; return address is pushed 

func:
   ; stack alignment 8 bytes
```

Во втором случае `sub rsp, 40` компенсирует эти 8 байт.

Вывод: если `func` это функция и вызывается через `call`, то она должна вести себя как функция.